# Should an API assign and return a reference number for newly created resources?

Tags: api, asp.net-web-api, conventions, restful-architecture

I am building a RESTful API where users may create resources on my server using post requests, and later reference them via get requests, etc. One thing I've had trouble deciding on is what IDs the clients should have. I know that there are many ways to do what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'd like to go with a design which follows industry conventions and best design practices.

Should my API decide on the ID for each newly created resource (it would most likely be the primary key for the resource assigned by the database)? Or should I allow users to assign their own reference numbers to their resources?

If I do assign a reference number to each new resource, how should this be returned to the client? The API has some endpoints which allow for bulk item creation, so I would need to list out all of the newly created resources on every response?

I'm conflicted because allowing the user to specify their own IDs is obviously a can of worms - I'd need to verify each ID hasn't been taken, makes database queries a lot weirder as I'd be joining on reference# and userID rather than foreign key. On the other hand, if I assign IDs to each resource it requires clients to have to build some type of response parser and forces them to follow my imposed conventions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wasn't practical (for me) to develop both of the above methods into my application, so I took a leap of faith and allowed the user to choose their own IDs. I quickly found that this complicated development so much that it would have added weeks to my development time, and resulted in much more complex and slow DB queries. So, early on in the project I went back and made it so that I just assign IDs for all created resources.

Life is simple now.

Other popular APIs that I looked at, such as the Instagram API, also assign IDs to certain created resources, which is especially important if you have millions of users who can interact with each-other's resources.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do both? Let the user create there reference and you create your own uid. If the users have to login then you can use there reference and userid unique key. I would also give the uid created back if not needed the client could ignore it.